# Use of a for loop in Java windowbuilder to produce multiple buttons n times

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton, windowbuilder

I want to create *n* buttons where *n* is the number of products stored in a HashMap and read from a text file. Each button, when clicked, will link to a JFrame containing information about that particular product.

I have attempted to use a for loop such as below:

```
    for(int i = 0; i == products.size(); i++) {
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(product_names[i]));
    }
```

Where `frame` is a private `JFrame` and `products` is the `HashMap` defined by `private Map<String, String[]> products = new HashMap<String, String[]>();` and filled using the following temporary method (to which in the future will fill from a text file):

```
private void loadProducts() {
    String[] product_info = {"temp","temp","temp","temp","temp","temp","temp","temp"};
    products.put("1", product_info);
    products.put("2", product_info);
    products.put("3", product_info);
}
```

Such that *n = 3* as there is 3 entries. However, when the program is run, no JButtons are shown on the 
frame, when there should be 3 different buttons for 3 different products.

`product_names` is simply a string array containing the key's of the HashMap. *i.e.*

```
private String[] product_names = {"1","2","3"};
```

Comment: Full code here https://pastebin.com/HnRuAZiN

Comment: Your for loop condition is wrong. You loop while `i` is equal to the size of the map, but `i` is initially zero, so it isn't equal, so the loop executes zero times.

Comment: `for (String name : product_names)` would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @DavidConrad thank you